# Set IAM Policy works on local machine but not in GCE instance

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

The following lines from my Python app execute with no problems on my local machine.

```
import googleapiclient.discovery
project_id = 'some-project-id'
resource_manager = googleapiclient.discovery.build('cloudresourcemanager', 'v1')
iam_policy_request = resource_manager.projects().getIamPolicy(resource=project_id, body={})
iam_policy_response = iam_policy_request.execute(num_retries=3)
new_policy = dict()
new_policy['policy'] = iam_policy_response
del new_policy['policy']['version']
iam_policy_update_request = resourcemanager.projects().setIamPolicy(resource=project_id, body=new_policy)
update_result = iam_policy_update_request.execute(num_retries=3)
```

When I run the app in a GCE instance, and more precisely from within a Docker container inside the GCE instance, I get the exception:

```
URL being requested: POST https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/some-project-id:setIamPolicy?alt=json
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 54, in error_remapped_callable
    return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 487, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, deadline)
  File "/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 437, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _Rendezvous(state, None, None, deadline)
grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with (StatusCode.PERMISSION_DENIED, User not authorized to perform this action.)>
```

i.e. an authorization error.  Oddly, when I open a Python terminal session inside the GCE instance and run the Python code line by line, I do not get the exception.  It only throws the exception when the code is running as part of the app.

I am using a service account inside of the GCE instance, as opposed to my regular account on my local machine.  But I don't think that is the problem since I am able to run the lines of code one by one inside of the instance while still relying on the service account roles.

I would like to be able to run the app without the exception within the Docker container inside of GCE.  I feel like I'm missing something but can't figure out what the missing piece is.

Answer (score 0):

Looking to your issue it seems  an authentication issue, because your application is not properly authenticated :

1- First run this command it will let your application temporarily use your own user credentials:
gcloud beta auth application-default login

the output should be like this:

Credentials saved to file: $SOME_PATH/application_default_credentials.json

2-Then you have set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS [environment](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#setting_the_environment_variable) variable to the path to the key file:

export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=$SOME_PATH/application_default_credentials.json

Try to run you Application after that.